# Why there are some print when the functin is not called in flask?

Tags: security, flask, decorator

The following code （pseudocode） in flask confused me a lot.

```
def IsIllegal(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args,**kwargs):
        if True:
            return error msg
        else:
            return f(*args,**kwargs)
    return decorated

@IsIllegal
@app.route(...,  methods = ['POST']  )
def func1():
    data = flask.request.get_data()
    print(data)
    ...
```

where function IsIllegal is used to check if the user is NOT logged in. What I found is that func1 always print the data even the user is not logged in. The return value of func1 is, as expected, stopped by the function IsIllegal. But I feel that it is not save because the statement in func1 is executed (the print). How can I understand this?

Comment: Can you make sure that you post **valid Python**? `return error msg` is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You registered the *undecorated* `func1()` function. The `@IsIllegal()` decorator result is applied after registration by the `@app.route()` decorator, and is never called when the route is accessed.

Decorators are applied in reverse order, from the inside out, so to speak. Reverse the decorators:

```
@app.route(...,  methods = ['POST']  )
@IsIllegal
def func1():
```

Now the result of `IsIllegal(func1)` is registered by `@app.route(...)`, so accessing the route will end up calling `decorated()`.